# AWS S3 PHP can I upload a file directly to a folder in a bucket

Tags: php, amazon-s3, amazon-web-services

What is the syntax for uploading a file directly to a folder in AWS S3 with the php sdk?

I was successful in uploading to a bucket using:

```
$response = $s3->create_object($bucket, $file_name, array('fileUpload' => $file_path))
```

tx!

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Try this way

```
$s3->create_object($bucket, 'folder/filename', $options)
```

Comment: Yes the keep in mind that there are no folders in S3.  You can use folder-like names such as `folder/filename` to present file hierarchies, but these are all simply files in a common data storage bucket.  So you need to explicitly prepend your file names with any folder-like identifier you would like to use.

Answer (score 7):

Simply do 1 thing, add 'path/'
ex: If you have a folder 'videos' in a bucket then you have to add path like this in 'key' =>'videos/video-name-here'.

```
try {
    // Upload data.
$result = $s3Client->putObject([
    'Bucket' => bucket-name,
    'Key'    => 'videos/video-name', //add path here
    'Body'   => fopen($video, 'r'),
    'ACL'    => 'public-read'
]);
print_r($result['ObjectURL']);

} catch (S3Exception $e) {
    echo $e->getMessage() . PHP_EOL;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Since all the answers here are pretty old, and this is the first result on Google, I'm posting the updated version:

```
$client = new \Aws\S3\S3Client([
    'region'  => '-- your region --',
    'version' => 'latest',
    'credentials' => [
        'key'    => "-- your IAM --",
        'secret' => "-- your secret --",
    ]
]);

$dir = '/local/directory';
$bucket = 'my-bucket';
$keyPrefix = '';
$options =[
    'params'      => ['ACL' => 'public-read'],
    'concurrency' => 20,
    'debug'       => true
];

$client->uploadDirectory($dir, $bucket, $keyPrefix, $options);
```

Answer (score -1):

This is another way you can try

```
    $this->Aws->bucket = 'bucket'
    $old_file = $dir. '/'.old_file_name;       
    $new_file = $dir. '/'.new_file_name;
    $file_permission = 'private';
    $this->Aws->upload($old_file , $new_file , $file_permission);
```